# unexpected token, but which token?

Tags: php, json

I have a link with a magento shop, which outputs the following json(please ignore the bogus values for testing purposes):

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/ZkZ4D/

**non pretty formatting, output by php**

```
[[{"customer_address_id":"4","created_at":"2013-01-14 10:49:59","updated_at":"2013-01-14 10:49:59","city":"abc town","country_id":"NL","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe","postcode":"7091 eh","street":"mwhahah 47\nmwhgahahahaha","telephone":"31645494440","is_default_billing":true,"is_default_shipping":true}],[{"customer_address_id":"4","created_at":"2013-01-14 10:49:59","updated_at":"2013-01-14 10:49:59","city":"abc town","country_id":"NL","firstname":"john","lastname":"doe","postcode":"7091 eh","street":"mwhahah 47\nmwhgahahahaha","telephone":"31645494440","is_default_billing":true,"is_default_shipping":true}]]
```

**pretty formatting for human reading**

```
[
    [
        {
            "customer_address_id": "4",
            "created_at": "2013-01-14 10:49:59",
            "updated_at": "2013-01-14 10:49:59",
            "city": "abc town",
            "country_id": "NL",
            "firstname": "john",
            "lastname": "doe",
            "postcode": "7091 eh",
            "street": "mwhahah 47\nmwhgahahahaha",
            "telephone": "31645494440",
            "is_default_billing": true,
            "is_default_shipping": true
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "customer_address_id": "4",
            "created_at": "2013-01-14 10:49:59",
            "updated_at": "2013-01-14 10:49:59",
            "city": "abc town",
            "country_id": "NL",
            "firstname": "john",
            "lastname": "doe",
            "postcode": "7091 eh",
            "street": "mwhahah 47\nmwhgahahahaha",
            "telephone": "31645494440",
            "is_default_billing": true,
            "is_default_shipping": true
        }
    ]
]
```

How do I get the above json?

**php code**

```
class ajax extends plantinaNLmagento
    {
    public function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();
        } 
    public function getCustomerAdressAjax()
        {
        $id = (int)$_GET['customerid'];
        $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_magento_users` WHERE `core_id`=:ID",array('ID'=>$id));
        $customeradresses = array();
        while($who = $q->fetchObject())
            {
            $x=$this->mage->call('customer_address.list',$who->magento_ID);
            array_push($customeradresses,$x); 
            array_push($customeradresses,$x);
            }
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($customeradresses);
        }
    }
```

I'm pushing the `$customeraddress` twice for testing purposes.

Now if I paste the resulting json into jsonlint or other json validators it all says it's valid json.

When I use it int he function JSON.parse or jQuery.parseJSON I get a unexected token error, but it doesn't say which token or where, and since my json passes the valdation I'm totally at a loss which token it fails at.

I must be missing something in the category of *facepalm* but I simply can't find it...

**error message**
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

Comment: Your JSON is valid. Problem lies elsewhere. Use your browser's developer tools > net inspector to see if your server is emitting PHP error/warnings/etc alongwith JSON.

Comment: And you are getting errors your fiddle for obvious reasons. You have a `\n` in the string which becomes a literal newline inside a string which is broken JavaScript (unterminated string literal) and therefore broken JSON.

Comment: @SalmanA You're a saviour! that's the problem I'm having!
Could you post it in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You JSON data is perfectly valid but you must also make sure that your PHP script sends only the JSON data and nothing else (notice, warning, error, etc will break the JSON).

To check, use your browser's development tools, FireBug, etc, and look at the network inspector tab to see the *actual* response sent by PHP. Fix them errors if necessary.

As for your fiddle: JSON data cannot be used inside JavaScript strings as-is. At minimum you must escape the backslashes (e.g. the JSON `"Hello\nWorld"` should become `'"Hello\\nWorld"'`).